# Using Powershell how can I bulk rename files recursively and include a counter in the new name?

Tags: powershell

I have a project where I need to search for multiple pdfs within multiple subfolders which contain a specific string and then rename them using a counter variable.  I'm a pretty novice powershell user but I think I've got it pretty close.  The only thing that is not working is the counter.  The counter variable never changes.  This is what I have so far for code:

```
$prefix = "sample"
$id = 1
Get-ChildItem -Filter "*combined*" -Recurse | Rename-Item -NewName ($prefix + ($id.tostring("000")) + '_regular_' + ($id.tostring("000")) + '.pdf' -f $id++ )
```

What am I missing?  Should I be using a 'foreach' loop?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you need to use a `ForEach` loop. This will go through and do the renames, ensuring that any files found in subdirectories are preserved in those directories after renaming

```powershell
Get-ChildItem -Filter "*combined*" -Recurse | %{ 
  $fullId = $id.toString("000")
  $curPath = Split-Path $_.FullName
  Rename-Item $_.fullname -NewName "$curPath\$($prefix)$($fullId)_regular_$($fullId).pdf" )
  $id += 1
}
```

Comment: Thanks.  This mostly did the trick, but I think the variable $id needs to be declared earlier.  Otherwise the first time through the loop, it returns as 'null'.

Comment: Er yeah that bit was kind of obvious, note I also left out `$prefix` because in your example you already defined that and `$id` before the bit you were having trouble with

Answer (score -1):

Here is my edited version of the above code:

```
$id = 1
Get-ChildItem -Filter "*combined*" -Recurse | %{ 
  $fullId = $id.toString("000")
  $curPath = Split-Path $_.FullName
  Rename-Item $_.fullname -NewName "$curPath\$($prefix)_$($fullId)_regular_$($fullId).pdf"
  $id++
}
```

Comment: So on Stack Overflow what you should do is upvote answers that you find helpful. If you're still having problems, you should make an edit to the question highlighting where. Taking the code I wrote and adding one line to it in order to answer your own question is not the correct way to use the site! Read the [information here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)